# Как указать несколько путей для компиляции шаблонов?

Tags: golang, echo

В руководстве приведен пример:

```
t := &Template{
    templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("public/views/*.html")),
}
```

в котором компилируются шаблоны по пути `public/views/*.html`.

Мне необходимо этот код изменить так, чтобы компилировались шаблоны не по одному, а по двум указанным путям, а именно `pjt_*/templates/include/*.html` и `pjt_*/templates/site/*.html`.

Мой код:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type TemplateRenderer struct {
    templates *template.Template
}

func (t *TemplateRenderer) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {

    if viewContext, isMap := data.(map[string]interface{}); isMap {
        viewContext["reverse"] = c.Echo().Reverse
    }

    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

func main() {
  e := echo.New()
  e.Renderer = &TemplateRenderer{
      // тут хочу, чтобы компилировались шаблоны, не только по
      // "pjt_*/templates/include/*.html", но и по "pjt_*/templates/site/*.html"
      templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("pjt_*/templates/include/*.html")),
  }

  e.GET("/something", func(c echo.Context) error {
      return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "template.html", "World")
  })

  e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8000"))
}
```

ПС руководство, на всякий: https://echo.labstack.com/guide/templates/

Comment: `pjt_*/templates/*/*.html`

Comment: В templates будут папки с шаблонами, которые не нужно компилировать. Поэтому, простите, буду настаивать на решении именно заданного вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Не ограничивайте себя только примерами из руководств, читайте документацию. Тогда вы точно найдёте для себя больше возможностей.

Например, обратите внимание на функцию [`template.ParseFiles`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#ParseFiles) - она создаёт шаблон из списка файлов.

Как получить список файлов по маске? Для этого есть функция [`filepath.Glob`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Glob)

Как объединить списки файлов, соответствующих разным маскам? Для этого подойдёт банальный встроенный `append`. Итого может получиться что-то вроде такого:

```
package main

import (
        "html/template"
        "path/filepath"
        "fmt"
)

const (
        INCLUDE_GLOB = `./pjt_*/templates/include/*.html`
        SITE_GLOB = `./pjt_*/templates/site/*.html`
)

func main() {
        files := []string{}
        includes, err := filepath.Glob(INCLUDE_GLOB)
        if err != nil { panic(err) }
        files = append(files, includes...)
        sites, err := filepath.Glob(SITE_GLOB)
        if err != nil { panic(err) }
        files = append(files, sites...)

        fmt.Printf("Files: %v\n", files)

        t, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
        if err != nil { panic(err) }
        println(t)
}
```

Я для примера положил в каждый каталог файлы с именами `a.html` и `b.html`. Получилось вот что:

```
Files: [pjt_1/templates/include/a.html pjt_1/templates/include/b.html pjt_2/templates/include/a.html pjt_2/templates/include/b.html pjt_1/templates/site/a.html pjt_1/templates/site/b.html pjt_2/templates/site/a.html pjt_2/templates/site/b.html]
```

Вроде как раз то, что вам нужно. Всего за пять минут чтения документации.

UPDATE

Как это использовать. `template.ParseFile` собирает коллекцию шаблонов. Ключом в этой коллекции служит имя файла - то, которое после последнего слеша. Поэтому если у вас есть несколько файлов с именем `template.html` в разных каталогах, то `ParseFile` запомнит последний встреченный файл `template.html`.

Ниже пример, который работает на моей машине. У меня структура файлов такая:

```
├── pjt_1
│   └── templates
│       ├── include
│       │   ├── a.html
│       │   └── b.html
│       └── site
│           ├── a.html
│           └── b.html
└── pjt_2
    └── templates
        ├── include
        │   ├── a.html
        │   └── b.html
        └── site
            ├── a.html
            └── b.html
```

В примере ниже эти файлы парсятся и собираются в шаблон. Я хочу вывести для запроса `/something` содержимое шаблона `a.html` - так и пишу:

```
e.GET("/something", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "a.html", "World")
    })
```

В результате выводится содержимое файла `pjt_2/templates/site/a.html`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type TemplateRenderer struct {
    templates *template.Template
}

func (t *TemplateRenderer) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {

    if viewContext, isMap := data.(map[string]interface{}); isMap {
        viewContext["reverse"] = c.Echo().Reverse
    }

    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

const (
    INCLUDE_GLOB = `./pjt_*/templates/include/*.html`
    SITE_GLOB    = `pjt_*/templates/site/*.html`
)

func main() {
    files := []string{}
    includes, err := filepath.Glob(INCLUDE_GLOB)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    files = append(files, includes...)
    sites, err := filepath.Glob(SITE_GLOB)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    files = append(files, sites...)

    fmt.Printf("Files: %v\n", files)

    e := echo.New()
    e.Renderer = &TemplateRenderer{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...)),
    }

    e.GET("/something", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "a.html", "World")
    })

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8000"))
}
```

Comment: Интересный код, благодарю, но не понимаю, как вывести страницу, сейчас так: `return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "template.html", "")`, и нынешний и полный путь не подключают шаблон

Comment: @JoiRip добавил как использовать шаблон